# Trouble installing nokogiri with RVM 1.9.3 on Centos 6.2

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm, nokogiri, libxml2

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': 
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

I have installed ruby 1.9.3 using RVM on my CentOS 6.2 server. When I try to run `gem install nokogiri` it produces the the output below. I have already visited the nokogiri website and installed the libxml2 and libxslt dependencies using yum:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
```

I have also installed the libxml2 and libxslt packages using `rvm pkg install` and reinstalled ruby afterward.

I have been searching for a solution, but I haven't found anything yet. Any ideas would be appreciated :)

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --with-iconv-dir
        --without-iconv-dir
        --with-iconv-include
        --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
        --with-iconv-lib
        --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
        --with-xml2-dir
        --without-xml2-dir
        --with-xml2-include
        --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
        --with-xml2-lib
        --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
        --with-xslt-dir
        --without-xslt-dir
        --with-xslt-include
        --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
        --with-xslt-lib
        --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
        --with-libxslt-config
        --without-libxslt-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libxml-2.0-config
        --without-libxml-2.0-config
        --with-libiconv-config
        --without-libiconv-config
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
        from extconf.rb:114:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Here are the contents of mkmf.log as requested:

```
package configuration for libxslt
cflags: -I/usr/include/libxml2
ldflags:
libs: -lxslt -lz -lm -lxml2

package configuration for libxml-2.0
cflags: -I/usr/include/libxml2
ldflags:
libs: -lxml2

package configuration for libiconv is not found
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/rvm/usr/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC  -g -DXP_UNIX -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include/libxml2   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-R/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic       -lxslt -lz -lm -lxml2   -lxml2   -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc "
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetLineNo@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsExtenderGroup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlMalloc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathIsNodeType@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrchr@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDtd@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCtxtCompile@LIBXML2_2.6.5'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSplitQName2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashUpdateEntry@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathEvalPredicate@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlRealloc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathContextSetCache@LIBXML2_2.6.25'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeURI@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlAddPrevSibling@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFindCharEncodingHandler@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashFree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSetProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `valuePop@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathIsNaN@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeIDTable@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashRemoveEntry2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPtrEval@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNextAncestor@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathInit@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashScan@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferCreateFd@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCompiledEval@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashAddEntry3@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeParserContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathErr@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictCreateSub@LIBXML2_2.6.5'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDocSetRootElement@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathObjectCopy@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictReference@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPtrNewContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewText@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewComment@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferClose@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferCat@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeDumpOutput@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashLookup3@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHasNsProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsDigitGroup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlDocContentDumpOutput@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathRegisterFunc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrPrintf@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrndup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSearchNs@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlValidateQName@LIBXML2_2.5.4'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlMutexLock@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNodeSetAddUnique@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlValidateNCName@LIBXML2_2.5.4'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeAddContent@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetID@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathRegisterFuncLookup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeRefTable@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrdup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlModuleSymbol@LIBXML2_2.6.17'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashUpdateEntry2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferFree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocText@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlUnlinkNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewChild@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeGetBase@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNodeSetMerge@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlMutexUnlock@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrstr@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictLookup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGenericError@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferWriteQuotedString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocPI@LIBXML2_2.6.15'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNumberFunction@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsBaseCharGroup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathWrapNodeSet@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeSetContent@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetIntSubset@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlParseURI@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetDtdAttrDesc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferAdd@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlParseDocument@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeNodeSet@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashCreate@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCastToString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCheckFilename@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlDocContentDumpFormatOutput@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewMutex@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlLoadExternalEntity@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlModuleOpen@LIBXML2_2.6.17'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCompile@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlNewDoc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathStringFunction@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDocCopyNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlAddID@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewNs@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewParserCtxt@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathConvertString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewNsProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetDocEntity@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeGetSpacePreserve@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathOrderDocElems@LIBXML2_2.5.6'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewParserContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictCreate@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathRegisterFuncNS@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathDebugDumpObject@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictQLookup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGenericErrorContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathEvalExpression@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlNewDocNoDtD@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashLookup2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferWriteString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferCreateFilename@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrncat@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrlen@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCharInRange@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDoc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlAddChild@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetCharEncodingName@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathRegisterVariableLookup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeCompExpr@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewCString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrncasecmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXIncludeProcessFlags@LIBXML2_2.6.3'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsCombiningGroup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNodeSetCreate@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashScanFull@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `inputPush@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrEqual@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `valuePush@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetNsList@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsBlankNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlURIEscapeStr@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCmpNodes@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCreateURI@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNextPrecedingSibling@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathIsInf@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictFree@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferCCat@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCompiledEvalToBoolean@LIBXML2_2.6.27'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferCreateFile@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSaveUri@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeParserCtxt@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeMutex@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocNodeEatName@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNodeSetAdd@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStringTextNoenc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSearchNsByHref@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathStringEvalNumber@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewCDataBlock@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewValueTree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferCreate@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashAddEntry2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeNodeList@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStringText@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathEval@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferFlush@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferContent@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNsLookup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlParserGetDirectory@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlUTF8Strloc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashRemoveEntry@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeObject@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewBoolean@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlUTF8Strpos@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrncmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsID@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFunctionLookupNS@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCtxtUseOptions@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetNsProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCastNodeToString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewTextLen@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeListGetString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashAddEntry@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlAllocOutputBuffer@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlModuleClose@LIBXML2_2.6.17'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSetNsProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathConvertNumber@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrcasecmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeGetContent@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCreateIntSubset@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCopyCharMultiByte@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashUpdateEntry3@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictOwns@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrcat@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStringCurrentChar@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewNodeSet@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlSetMetaEncoding@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashLookup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBuildURI@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

Comment: Can you paste the contents of mkmg.log

Comment: You need to provide the contents of your mkmf.log file in order for anyone to give you advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this, somehow. I removed all of the rvm packages (libxml2, iconv, libxslt, etc.) except for zlib using `rvm pkg uninstall <package>` I then re-installed 1.9.3 using `rvm reinstall 1.9.3`

Then I did a `gem install nokogiri` and it worked just fine...

I don't completely understand why it works now, perhaps the libxml2, iconv, libxslt rvm packages are bad?

Comment: I did some changes in my environment related to those libraries and due that my Ruby install was broken. After reinstalling it, nokogiri installed just fine, thanks.

Comment: is there any way of uninstalling all the rvm packages excluding zlib in one go? thanks

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that gem install nokogiri call `path/to/your/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb`,and in `extconf.rb` file,

> LIB_DIRS = [
>       # First search /opt/local for macports
>       '/opt/local/lib',
>
> ```
> # Then search /usr/local for people that installed from source
> '/usr/local/lib',
>
> # Check the ruby install locations
> LIBDIR,
>
> # Finally fall back to /usr
> '/usr/lib',
> ```

but your libxml2 lib may not at above paths.so you must make sure extconf.rb can find your libxml2 lib
**My solution:**
My centos is 64bit,libxml2 is installed at /usr/lib64,and I copy `usr/lib64/libxml2.so` to `/usr/lib/libxml2.so`  to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue seems to be that your rvm/brew/port/whatever binaries compiled for Lion are going to have some outdated/removed library dependencies, causing both compilation and runtime issues for higher-level software. I fixed this on my system by nuking all my brew and port-managed packages, recompiling/reinstalling all my dependencies, recompiling my RVM-managed ruby 1.9.3-p194, and finally `gem install nokogiri' worked without issues.

I wasted a lot of time trying to convince my outdated compiled packages work. Instead, just reinstall the aforementioned (making sure you're actually recompiling/linking) and you should be fine.

Comment: Do you mean reinstall ruby 1.9.3-p194? I've tried doing this through rvm but is hasn't solved the problem? Might this be because its not recompiling/linking and if so how do I make sure it is recompiling/linking?

Comment: You also have to uninstall any dependency packages that you may have installed with RVM as well (libxml2, libiconv, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

(on CentOS 7.0.1406 Core)